# Calculating SE for set of proportions with different sample sizes

Tags: r, standard-error, proportion

Okay, so I have a data set where I'm measuring survival rates under different conditions. I have three treatments, control, pH 1, and pH 2. Each one has six replicates, all of which have different sample sizes and survival counts. So for example, the control has the following proportions:

15/300,
10/150,
28/525,
0/230,
27/438, and
5/86

So I know I could calculate the percent survival of each replicate and then do the SE from those six values, but that doesn't seem right b/c it doesn't account for the different sample sizes. Is there a way to calculate essentially a weighted SE in this instance? I'm using ggplot to plot these by the way.

Comment: If you calculated the %s & SEs for 15/300 & 10/150, how would that not take into account the differing sample sizes? You are dividing by 300 vs 150.

Comment: Because if you just had the percentages, you can't tell what sample size they came from. Let's use 10/150 for example. That's 6.667%, but you would get that same percent from 10,000/150,000, as well as 1/15. To me, the larger sample size features more prominently in the mean than lower sample size replicates, so it seems intuitive that there should be some weighting in the SE calculation as well?

Comment: From your example data, it seems you don't just have the percentages. Which is good as, if you only had %s, you wouldn't be able to compute the SEs. If you had %s & Ns, you could calculate the original numerators.